# How to hide URL variable in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Web route is

```
Route::post('/loginext/{username}/{password}', 'LoginControllerExt@checkLogin');
```

while calling the url

```
http://localhost/old/loginext/bank/test
```

It will call the controller and get the response. But that time the url is

```
http://localhost/old/loginext/bank/test
```

I want to show the url as

```
 http://localhost/old/
```

LoginControllerExt Controller

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request)
{
             $LoginID=$request->username;
             $Password=$request->password;
             $Status='Success';

if($Status == 'Success' ) {
            return view('dashboard.index'); 
                          }
}
```

Comment: pass the values in request body rather than sending in URL.

Comment: You can't. unless you use a post request and add the credentials in the body.

Comment: Don't make your route `/loginext/{username}/{password}` then, use the request to send credentials

Comment: How to  pass in request body?

Comment: You are using form ?

Comment: Not answering your question but - you should **absolutely**, **definitely** **not** include the password in the URL.  It will be visible in the browser (eg someone sitting beside you will see it), and available in browser history (eg someone clicks back, or views history), as well as logged in the web server's logfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Change route as

```
Route::post('/loginext', 'LoginControllerExt@checkLogin');
```

Pass the credentials in request body.Try with postman.

[Check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzvq.png)

In controller

```
public function checkLogin(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: while  I tried to echo the variables using  http://localhost/old/loginext/bank/test url it showing 404 error